# My JavaScript code does not work because of querySelector

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to java script and have a long way to go off learning, and attempted to make something but it doesn't not work.

Here's the code:

```
var LIS = document.getElementsByClassName("Links")[0].querySelector("ul").querySelector("li").querySelector("a");

for (let Index in LIS){
  LIS[Index].mouseenter = function(){
    console.log("Test");
  };
};
```

Here's the error I get
[Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuhoQ.png)

```
function main(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("Links")[0].querySelector("ul").querySelector("li").querySelector("a").onmouseenter = function(){
        console.log("Test")
    }
}
```

This one didn't log anything in the console.

Comment: Share your html

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Seems like `document.getElementsByClassName("Links")` does not find anything. Either that's not the correct class name, or you're trying to look up the documents before they exist in the document.

Comment: Unrelated to the current error but `for (let Index in LIS)` is also wrong: since you use `.querySelector()` that means `LIS` will be a single DOM element and you'd be iterating over that element's attributes, rather through each item in a collection.

Comment: What is unclear about an error message such as _“Cannot read property `querySelector` of `undefined`”_? You can’t read properties of `undefined`, but that’s what happens at `document.getElementsByClassName("Links")[0].querySelector` because `document.getElementsByClassName("Links")[0]` is `undefined`; it’s trying to get `querySelector` off of `undefined` — not possible. If you don’t know why `document.getElementsByClassName("Links")[0]` is `undefined`, use the debugger or look at intermediate values: `console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("Links"));`.

Comment: Is your `<script>` _above_ your HTML with no `defer` attribute and no `DOMContentLoaded` or `load` listener and is not `type="module"`? See [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementById` not find the element?](/q/14028959/4642212). The current best practice is to include your JavaScript code as a [module](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) using `<script type="module" src="path/to/code.mjs"></script>` which solves this problem and many more.